# Get String from Replace function with regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

How to get string that is present in regular expression.

**Input**: For example `HtmlContent` contains string

```
"<% CustomerSignUpURL ||Text:Hello Abhishek %>"
```

**Output**: after replacing string should be anchor tag like below:

```
Hello Abhishek //  where Hello Abhishek is anchor tag
```

Please help me with the code what should be there in place of question mark given below:

```
campaignInfo.HtmlContent = campaignInfo.HtmlContent.replace(
    /<% CustomerSignUpURL ||Text:([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+) %>/g,
    '<a href="<% CustomerSignUpURL %>">{????}</a>'
);
```

Comment: I think you're just looking for `$1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the content of the tag by:

```
const tagContent = campaignInfo
    .HtmlContent
    .match(/CustomerSignUpURL \|\|(.*):(.*)%>/)[2];

// then replace it with:
campaignInfo.HtmlContent = campaignInfo.HtmlContent.replace(
    /<% CustomerSignUpURL \|\|Text:.+?(?=>)./g,
    `<a href="<% CustomerSignUpURL %>">${tagContent}</a>`
);
```

Comment: what will be the name of anchor tag? I want it to be dynamic text Example: Hello Abhishek